# CMake FindBoost for -mt-s library suffix

Tags: boost, 64-bit, cmake, flags, nmake

First things first: Windows 7 x64 using Microsoft CL.exe command line compiler with CMake, properly configured on the amd64 Visual Studio command line.  I have walked through a few basic problems (e.g. I was trying to link against shared instead of static Boost, I was trying to link against x86 Boost with an x64 target, etc) and now that I've gotten those straight, I'm trying to wrap my head around CMake flags for Boost.

I've got the idea of the different nomenclatures for Boost (like what -mt-gd means.)  My Boost libraries are all -mt-s (Release multithreaded.)

I'd like to know which CMake variable for FindBoost corresponds to the -g and -d suffixes.

Here's my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

project( echoserv )

set( APP_NAME Echoserv )
set( MAIN_SOURCE echoserv.cpp )
set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELEASE" )

set( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON )
set( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON )
set( Boost_DEBUG ON )

find_package( Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED )

add_executable( ${APP_NAME} ${MAIN_SOURCE} )

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
link_directories( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( ${APP_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

The resulting error when I try to compile is:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

This is because my Boost libraries are all of the form "-vc100-mt-s-1_53.lib".  So what flags should I use to get it to link with the -mt-s libs and stop trying to link against -mt-gd?

Resources:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming 
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost

Clearly the cmake.org link should be of use, but I think I'm setting the variables correctly, and it's still trying to link against mt-gd.

Edit: here is the output with set Boost_DEBUG ON:

(note that Boost libraries are installed to %LIB%.)

```
E:\fastmeta\dev\workspace\personal\learncpp\socks\echoserv>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:566 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:568 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:570 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:572 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = ON
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:574 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:576 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:644 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:646 ]   BOOST_ROOT =
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:648 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR =
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:650 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:652 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:734 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:754 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.53.0
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:786 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc100
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:796 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:839 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -s
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:841 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -sgd
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:884 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/../lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/stage/lib;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_53_0/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_53/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:962 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_53;libboost_system-vc100-mt-s;libboost_system-mt-s-1_53;libboost_system-mt-s;libboost_system
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:994 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_53;libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd;libboost_system-mt-sgd-1_53;libboost_system-mt-sgd;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system
-- [ E:/fastmeta/dev/tools/cmake/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1108 ] Boost_FOUND = TRUE
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/fastmeta/dev/workspace/personal/learncpp/socks/echoserv
Linking CXX executable Echoserv.exe
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_53.lib'

LINK failed. with 2
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"E:\fastmeta\dev\tools\cmake\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe
"' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: Further reading:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2011-12/txta1SOQqu6kA.txt

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, can you add the output of your CMake command after changing to `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)`?

Comment: Added the debug output.  Note that Boost libraries are installed to the %LIB% amd64 directory.

Comment: And you've deleted your CMakeCache.txt before re-running CMake?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, there isn't a way to tell CMake to only find the Release versions of Boost if you've built both.  And on Windows, if you plan to build your project in Debug and Release, you'd normally build Debug and Release versions of Boost too, since they each link to different versions of the C Runtime Library;  i.e. normally you'd have not just libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_53.lib, but also libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_53.lib in the same folder.

So with your CMakeLists.txt as it is just now (assuming the boost root dir is found properly), the value of `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` should be something like:

```
optimized;<path to boost root>/stage/lib/libboost_system-vc100-mt-s-1_53.lib;debug;<path to boost root>/stage/lib/libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_53.lib
```

Then when you do [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries)`( ${APP_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )` you're saying which version of the boost lib to link against depending on whether it's a Debug or Release build.

The fact that VS is looking for libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib makes me think that this may be down to boost's autolinking feature.  Certainly with the `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)` line, CMake shouldn't even be looking for libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib.

You can turn off Boost's autolinking feature by adding the following line:

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
```

Comment: Hi Fraser, thanks for your reply.  I've only built the Release version.  How do you tell it to only link against Release?

Comment: If you've only provided the Release versions of the Boost libs, then `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` will only contain those (without any `optimized` or `debug` args) and should be used whether you're building in Debug or Release.

Comment: Are you definitely compiling your program with the `/MT` flag set (i.e. using static CRT) and not `/MD`?  If you have a mismatch like this (boost compiled with `/MT` and yours compiled with `/MD`) *and* you don't have `add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)`, then you'd get an error message similar to the one you're seeing.  But I'd also expect it to contain a bit more about the reason.